# Select all un-selected boxes in multi-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get all the unchecked boxes in a multi-selector? To get the selected boxes I have:

```
$("#studentsWeek1Room21 option:selected").each(function(){
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Attempting to get the unchecked ones:

```
$("#studentsWeek1Room21 option:not(selected)").each(function(){
    unselectedValues.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#studentsWeek1Room21 option").not(":selected").each(function(){
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't work out how to get the code to show on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a colon before selected

```
$("#studentsWeek1Room21 option:not(:selected)").each(function(){
```